# OpenGL ES 3.0. Floating point texture

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es

I have OpenGL ES 3.0 and I'm trying to create a texture:

```
case 1: glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R16F, width, height, 0, GL_RED, GL_HALF_FLOAT, 0); break;
case 2: glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RG16F, width, height, 0, GL_RG, GL_HALF_FLOAT, 0); break;
case 3: glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB16F, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_HALF_FLOAT, 0); break;
```

(for this code glGetError() return 0)

```
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureHandle, 0);
```

But when attaching to framebuffer the glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) return 36054.

```
Surface CreateSurface(GLsizei width, GLsizei height, int numComponents)
{
 GLuint fboHandle;
 glGenFramebuffers(1, &fboHandle);
 glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fboHandle);

 GLuint textureHandle;
 glGenTextures(1, &textureHandle);
 glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureHandle);
 glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
 glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
 glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
 glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

 switch (numComponents) {
        case 1: glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R16F, width, height, 0, GL_RED, GL_HALF_FLOAT, 0); break;
        case 2: glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RG16F, width, height, 0, GL_RG, GL_HALF_FLOAT, 0); break;
        case 3: glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB16F, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_HALF_FLOAT, 0); break;
        default: PezFatalError("Illegal slab format.");
    }


 PezCheckCondition(GL_NO_ERROR == glGetError(), "Unable to create normals texture");

 GLuint colorbuffer;
 glGenRenderbuffers(1, &colorbuffer);
 glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, colorbuffer);
 glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureHandle, 0);
 PezCheckCondition(GL_NO_ERROR == glGetError(), "Unable to attach color buffer");

 PezCheckCondition(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE == glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER), "Unable to create FBO.");
 Surface surface = { fboHandle, textureHandle, numComponents };

 glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
 glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
 glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

 return surface;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Textures attached to **GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENTn** are required to use color-renderable format. Unfortunately, float formats are not color-renderable. For list of color-renderable formats, check **Table 3.12** in http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/3.0/es_spec_3.0.2.pdf

Comment: Thanks! But perhaps I can somehow get the floating-point texture?

Comment: Try using **GL_RGBA16F** instead of **GL_RGB16F** for **case 3**.

Comment: But in this case, I'll again get the same not color-renderable texture. Maybe I can somehow convert values in the shader or somehow otherwise?

Comment: I would try it (GLRGBA16F) anyway. Do you get the same error for first two cases? Maybe you could tell something more about what you are trying accomplish... what is the end goal?

Comment: It is possible that an extension will come along and make floating-point image formats color-renderable, and the GLES 3.0 spec will never mention this. It was the same way in GLES 2.0, none of the useful image formats are color-renderable, but lots of people use them anyway without even checking whether the hardware supports the appropriate extension :P

Comment: Srđan Tot, I'm tried, but the same result - the glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) return 36054. In the end I want to get the motion of particles and I need more accuracy for this.

Comment: Andon M. Coleman, if my device supports an extension EXT_color_buffer_float, the code would have worked perfectly, but it is not.